# Is there a way to color a face instead of vertex?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have two 3D cubes that share the same vertices but have different faces. (one is places upon the other).

Is there a way to tell unity how to color the faces instead of the vertices?

Thanks you

I have looked for solutions online but could not find any

Answer (score 1):

## By not using Vertex Color

Vertex Color, as the name suggests, is color data *per vertex.* If you want something else you need to use something like, like a diffuse map (a texture).

In theory you could write your own shader to read vertex color information and discard the values that don't match, but this would likely be an exercise in frustration.